# Abort creation if reply to client failed in restful webservice

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm trying to create restful microservice.

So I have a client service and server service.

Client service wants to create and update some entitites via http with rest. And the server provides the service for that.

The client have a persitent state. Part of that state is entities that he created. So he need to store 'ids' of entities that server created for him.

One problem that I'm thinking about is what to do when client failed when server was executing create operation. So client executes /entities/ POST

Server gets the request and replies with {id = n, ...}, but client already dead.

So now client can't restore it's state after fail.

I know of course that I can do that without using http with persistent message queue and request-reply pattern (via rabbitmq or something else) but I really wan't to create a restful service.

PS And of course It can be achieved with storing storing client state on server one way or another. Like using some link to client in entity.